# Kotlin : Как получить данные из CoroutineScope

Tags: kotlin, coroutine

Есть код корутины:

```kotlin
fun startcoroutin (pegenamber:Int) {
    //запуск загрузки json in corotine
    job?.cancel()
    job = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
         var jsonlist = LoadJson().loadjsonlist(pegenamber) //  это suspend            
    }
}
```

Каким образом можно из этой функции вернуть значение `jsonlist`?

При такой попытке возникает ошибка:

```kotlin
fun startcoroutin (pegenamber:Int):JSONObject {
    //запуск загрузки json in corotine
    job?.cancel()
    job = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
        var jsonlist = LoadJson().loadjsonlist(pegenamber) //  это suspend    
    }
    return jsonlist  //   не видит переменную из корутины 
}
```

Comment: Короткий ответ: присвойте это значение чему-то, что существует за пределами корутины. А вообще эта тема (асинхронное программирование) обширная. Callback, channel, LiveData -- изучайте эти темы.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать вместо `launch` функцию `async`, которая возвращает вычисленное значение:

```
fun startCoroutine(pageNumber: Int) = scope.async {
        var jsonList = LoadJson().loadjsonlist(pageNumber)
        return@async jsonList
    }
```

Затем вызвать `await` для получения результата, например:

```
Log.i(startCoroutine(5).await())
```